# Prove that for all $e \gt 0$, there exists $d \gt 0$ such that for all $x \gt 0$, if $x \lt d$, then ${x^2} \lt e$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I tried to prove this using the contrapositive, but got stuck on $x^2\ge e \rightarrow x\ge d$. But how would I go from there?

Comment: Have you tried Archimedean property of real numbers ??

Comment: Can you check your question? is there any mistake in your question?

Comment: @AnikBhowmick I don't know what that is. I will look it up. If possible, could you ELI5 that concept to me?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Yeah this the question.

Comment: Well, Archimedean property says that for any $x > 0$ and $y$, you'll find a natural number $n$, such that $nx > y$. $x$ and $y$ must be elements of an ordered field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of $P\to Q$ is $\lnot Q\to \lnot P$.

Contrapositive of $x>d \to x^2<e$ is $x^2\ge e \to x\le d$.

Since it is $\forall x>0$, one can let $x=d+e$, then: $x^2=(d+e)^2\ge e \not\to x=d+e\le d$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I wrote the question wrong. Truly sorry. How would I do it with the correct wording? x < d, not x > d.

Comment: using contrapositive: $x^2\ge e \to x\ge d$. Case 1: $e\ge 1$. Then: $x\ge \sqrt{e}\ge \sqrt[3]{e}=d$. Case 2: $0<e<1$. Then: $x\ge \sqrt{e}> e=d$.

Comment: Why is the cube root of e equal to d?

Comment: it is stated that there exists such $d$, so you can choose $d$ equal to the cube root of $e$.

Comment: What kind of black magic sorcery is this???? So why are two cases necessary?

Comment: try numbers in the given intervals. for example, when $e=2$, then $x\ge \sqrt{2}\ge \sqrt[3]{2}=d$. when $0<e=0.25<1$, then $x\ge \sqrt{0.25}>0.25=d$.

Answer (score 3):

- The contrapositive of $x > d \implies x^2 < e$ is $x^2 \ge e \implies x \le d$.
- The statement of the question states that for very large $x$, it is bounded from above which is clearly not true.
- For example, let $e=1$, for any positive $d$, let $x = \max(2d, e)$, then we have $x > d$ and $x^2 = \max(4d^2, e^2)= \max(4d^2, 1) \ge 1$

Comment: I messed up the wording. x > d, not x < d. Sorry! How would I do it with the revised wording?

Comment: I changed it, it is right now.

Comment: that depends on what tools do you have currently.  If you have the notion of square root, you can pick $d$ to be its square root of $e$.

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite obvious... I think. If you fix such an $e$, then find an $x$ such that $x^2 < e$. You'll always find it. Fix that $x$. Then take a $d$ such that $d < x$. Again, you'll always find such $d$. 
I think from Archimedean property and density of $\mathbb R^+$, it follows.

Comment: Firstly, we don't have to "find" $e$. We will be given it. Also, the result must be true for "every" $x$ with the stated property. The theorem statement does not seem true.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually we have nothing to prove here I guess.

Comment: I messed up the wording. It's supposed to be x < d not x > d. Sorry!

Comment: Still you'll find such $d$. Density of $\mathbb R$ will help you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You first write down a number $d$ such that $d^2 < e$. Then
If $0 < x < d$ you have $x^2 < d^2 < e$.

So try to find this number $d$. You might consider breaking into cases $e < 1$ and $e \geq 1$.